# Crop the image using tensoflow Imagegenerator preprocessing fucntion by opencv

Tags: python, tensorflow-serving

i create a function for croping eye image. because outer side of eye image is balack and unnecessary pixel .but if i using this function  for loading image in opencv ,for large resolution ,allocate the memory. i want to crop the image using tensorflow imagedatagenerator preprocessing function  by opencv .
'crop_image' is my function and its work properly.
train is a path . train> Normal and abnormal file  where image are stored

```
def preprocessing_fun(train):

  img=cv2.imread(train,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
  img=crop_image(img)
        
  if img is not None:
    image=cv2.resize(img,(512,512))
    img=cv2.addWeighted ( image,4, cv2.GaussianBlur( image , (0,0) ,224/10) ,-4 ,128) 
    return img
  img_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                           preprocessing_function = 
  preprocessing_fun)
training_gen = img_datagen.flow_from_directory(train, target_size=(224,224),
                          color_mode='rgb',batch_size=32,)
```

after using this  it see the number of image but show a error :
SystemError:  returned NULL without setting an error
how to solve this problem??

Answer (score 0):

your cv2.imread is not reading one image according to your function because cv2.imread only can read one image at a time.

For example: let's say if in your function train is a list then you can read by using for loop (for image in train:) something like that